# Pandas dataframe multi-index indexing

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this:

```
           d
a  b  c     
a1 b1 c1  10
   b2 c2  11
a2 b3 c3  12
   b4 c4   1
a3 b5 c5   2
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are `multi_index` columns, and I was trying to reference some rows according to one or more index column's values. How can I use some combination of these index columns to filter rows? I tried to use `.loc`, but didn't get the results I wanted:

The ideal scenario would be to pass a list with the index values I want, so that I could just pass the parameters I want, dynamically. But in the example below, it didn't work.

```
>>> x.loc[['a1', 'b1', 'c1']]
           d
a  b  c     
a1 b1 c1  10
   b2 c2  11
```

I see that this works:

```
>>> x.loc['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
d    10
```

But `x.loc['a1', 'c1']` returns error.

After all, how `.loc` works when dealing with `multi-index` values? I didn't find other questions answering this problem (maybe because I'm using the wrong keywords, I don't know...).

My final goal is to use the values of the columns of multi-index (sometimes not all columns) and get the correspondent rows.

Comment: To get your third example to work, you can use `x.loc['a1', :, 'c1']`.  Pandas can't guess which level you are trying to index, it uses positional based lookup

Comment: x.loc[['a1','lalalala','a2']], it will lookup the first level of multiple index match ~

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Answer (score 0):

There may also be different results depending on which version of pandas you're using.
Looking at your example, since your dataframe only has one column, be careful that it isn't converted to a series at some point.

```py
# Code to illustrate pandas upgrade:
import pandas as pd
cats = ['A', 'B']
groups = ['x','y','z']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((cats,groups))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(6), index=idx)  # Dataframe
ser = pd.Series(data=range(6), index=idx)  # Series

df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A','y':],:] # This works for both pandas
ser.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A','y':],:] # This only works in older pandas
ser.loc[pd.IndexSlice['A','y':]] # This works in new pandas and old pandas`
```

The error that is thrown by pandas 1.2.x is:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```